# Load AD group members to include nested groups c#

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

I am using AD to populate a list of the company associates.
I have an AD group from which I am iterating through (using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement) to populate the list. The group in question contains some nested groups (following a recent company merger) but it seems the nested group members aren't being included.

```
// get the members of the specified AD group...
        GroupPrincipal group = adm.GetGroup(AdGroupName);            

        // iterate over its members
        foreach (Principal p in group.Members)
        {                
// get the data for the user...
            var groupMember = adm.GetUser(p.SamAccountName);
```

From here I determine if the user is enabled and not expired and if both true, add their name to a sorted list (which I cache for 24 hours) due to it's size.
Is there anything I need to do to get the nested groups included, or do I have to append the second group to the end?

Answer (score 1):

OK, so a bit more googling and I found this...

```
foreach (Principal p in @group.GetMembers(true))
```

So instead of getting the members, you recursively get all members!